# Find sum of arguments where function takes supremum and infimum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f(x)=(\tan x)^{\sin 2x} $ $\\$ for $x\in(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ let $i$ be an argument where function takes infimum and $s$ - supremum. Find $i+s$

I calculated $f'(x)=2e^{\sin2x\cdot\ln{\tan x}}\cdot(\cos 2x\ln{\tan x}+1)$ and we have $2e^{\sin2x\cdot\ln{\tan x}}$ is always positve so it all comes down to find out where $\cos 2x\ln{\tan x}+1$ is positive and where negative but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. But I hope this will helps someone to answer this problem.

Let $x=\tan\theta$ then $$\sin 2\theta=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$$ Let $$y=x^{\frac{2x}{1+x^2}}$$ on $x\in(0,\infty).$ $$\ln y=\frac{2x\ln x}{1+x^2}$$ $$\lim_{x\to 0,\infty}\ln y=0$$ Therefore $$\lim_{x\to 0,\infty} y=1.$$

Here I also gave a sketch of your function on the given domain using mathematica.
[image]